# Docker build with opencv dependency doesn't work

Tags: python, docker, opencv, pip, raspberry-pi

I have a problem with building a docker from a python script. The script should take photos on a raspberry pi, anonymize the photo and save it in a firebase storage (and the filename in a postgres database). It runs as a flask server - so whenever the firebase config is send in a request the script is starting to run. The docker should run on a raspberry pi and is also build on one to avoid architecture problems - the raspberry pi has an armhf architecture.
My main problem seems to be the opencv dependeny I need for anonymizing the picture.

My docker file currently looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app

ENV TZ=Europe/Berlin

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y libopencv-dev libpq-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev python3-opencv gnupg build-essential cmake

RUN echo "deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ buster main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-key 7FA3303E


RUN apt-get install -y libraspberrypi0 libraspberrypi-dev libraspberrypi-doc libraspberrypi-bin

COPY take_pic_and_insert.py .

RUN pip install Flask==2.1.1

RUN pip install Werkzeug==1.0.1

RUN pip install psycopg2==2.9.1

RUN pip install pyrebase==3.0.27

RUN pip install numpy==1.16.6

RUN pip install picamera

RUN pip install opencv-python

CMD ["python", "take_pic_and_insert.py"]
```

It all runs through fine until pip install opencv-python runs. First of all it takes forever (around 1h) and currently always ends in the following error:

```
6904.7       Failed to build numpy
6904.7       ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I have the feeling the versions of the dependencies don't match but I can't really check that since the build runs forever and it would take weeks to throughly try out the possibilities.

Did anybody face a similar problem before? How did you solve it?

Comment: The newer version released January 2024. py -m pip install numpy --upgrade  Successfully installed numpy-1.26.3